# Result of 'File.delete()' is ignored

Tags: java, delete-file

I was trying to make a button which can delete a file (video file) which is downloaded by the app.

When I used `File.delete()` then the android studio says it will be ignored and by that I came to know that this is a problem with the Security stuff in android. And I would like to SURELY delete the file (in my case it is the video file downloaded by my app). Hope anyone help me out.

Here is the code I used:

```
path = "/some/folder/"
File file = new File(path);
file.delete();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, there's not enough information in question for someone to give you a reasonable answer. For tips on writing questions read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @HopeyOne On the contrary. The information provided is pertectly adequate.

Comment: I concur with @user207421.  The question, and answer, are perfectly clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning that you are seeing is telling you that `file.delete()` returns a value, and that you are ignoring that returned value.

The issue is that you cannot know that the file was actually deleted unless you check that the call to `file.delete()` returns `true`.

So, to eliminate this warning, evaluate the return value, and appropriately handle the case where it is `false`.

Comment: Yeah, I have checked that file isn't' getting deleted and the code I used for checking is given below. And I would like to surely delete the file. But how can I successfully delete the file? (In my case the file is a video file in which is downloaded by app and my app is an LMS app).

if (file.delete())
                Utils.showTost(context, "File deleted");
            else Utils.showTost(context, "Failed To Delete File");

Comment: You can't always execute what you want. The question is, why not?  Unfortunately `FIle.delete` doesn't tell you why not.   You might prefer to use [the `Files.delete` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)) (note the 's') which will raise an exception on failure. Your code can then handle the exception to find out why the delete failed.

Comment: Yeah, haha. That's true.

Comment: What if I don't care about the result? I want to delete the File if it exists. If it doesn't and File.delete() fails, I don't care.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue.

The issue is THE FILE I AM TRYING TO DELETE DOES NOT EXIST. I HAVE NOT MENTIONED THE CORRECT DIRECTORY (whereas I need to mention another folder in which my files exist)

Thanks [GreyBeardedGeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982341/greybeardedgeek) for saying me to know if the file.delete() returns true or false so that I can handle it if it returns false.

#FirstStackOverflowQuestionResolved :-)